# How to call a function from onClick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that starts when you click the button. I can't seem to get the function to be called with the onclick. What is the proper syntax for calling a function with string parameters from onclick? I tried:

```
onclick="countDown(10, 'status')"
```

but that doesn't work. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Demo:

```js
function countDown(secs,elem) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);

  element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
  if(secs<1){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
    element.innerHTML += '<a href="#"> Click here now</a>';

  }

  secs--;
  var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>

<form>
  <input type="submit" name="go" onclick="countDown(5, 'status'); return false;">
</form>
```

http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/WrGxYp

Comment: Doesn't work - what is the issue?

Comment: In the Demo it works very well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the correct syntax (at least if you are going to use intrinsic event attributes), however you have used it on a submit button so a split second after the function runs, the form submits and it loads a new page (which wipes out the changes you made with JS).

You can return false from the onclick function to prevent the default behaviour:

```
onclick="countDown(10, 'status'); return false;"
```

Modern code would lean towards using JavaScript to bind event handlers.

```
document
    .querySelector("input[type=submit]")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        countDown(10, 'status');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call your javascript function from button click like this :
use this

```
    <input type="submit" name="go" onclick="countDown(10, 'status'); return false">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a submit type of button. Return `false` if you need to avoid submitting the form:

```
<div id="status"></div>

<form>
<input type="submit" name="go" onclick="countDown(10, 'status'); return false;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things, look for the changes here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPggNJ

Summary:

- you have a local variable `secs` which is always decremented from the starting level 10, so it's always `9` and never gets less than that
- The submit control type immediately sends the form and reloads the page
- setting a timer even when the value of `secs`is less than 0 due to missing return

The above linked fork works as expected.